# WFS feature caching in QGIS hitting feature limit

Tags: qgis, wfs, cache

I am using QGIS 2 and using a WFS with a 5,000 feature limit.

When I load a dataset without caching the features and it hits the 5,000 feature limit, QGIS seems to give up on reloading data. When I zoom in on the dataset, it continues to request the WFS from the original extent, reloading the data, but not in the new extent.

The upshot of it is that when I load a dataset, hit the limit and zoom in, I still can't see the entire dataset without removing and re-adding the dataset

Is this something wrong with the way I have QGIS set up, or is it something to do with the WFS settings?